# Scraper throws an error even if right xpath is used

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've written a script in python in combination with lxml libary to parse some `price` (80 and 100 in this case) out of a chunk of `html elements`. I used `xpaths` to do the job. When I go for using `.fromstring()` then both the `xpaths` I've used within my below scraper work flwlessly. However, when I choose to go with `HTML` imported from `lxml.etree` then the xpath containig `contains()` expression fails. Turns out that when I use multiple `class` names within the scraper, it works but when choose a `single class name` out of `compound class names` then it throws an error.

How can I handle such situation without using `compound class names`;rather, using a `single class name` following `.contains()` pattern or something?

This is my try:

```
from lxml.etree import HTML

elements =\
"""
    <li class="ProductPrice">
      <span class="Regular Price">80.00</span>
    </li>
    <li class="ProductPrice">
      <span class="Regular Price">100.00</span>
    </li>
"""
root = HTML(elements)
for item in root.findall(".//*[@class='ProductPrice']"):
    # regular = item.find('.//span[@class="Regular Price"]').text
    regular = item.find('.//span[contains(@class,"Regular")]').text
    print(regular)
```

Btw, the commented out `xpath` used within above script is working fine. But can't go fo `.contains()` expression which throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\WCS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\SO.py", line 15, in <module>
    regular = item.find('.//span[contains(@class,"Regular")]').text
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1526, in lxml.etree._Element.find
  File "src\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 311, in lxml._elementpath.find
  File "src\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 300, in lxml._elementpath.iterfind
  File "src\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 283, in lxml._elementpath._build_path_iterator
  File "src\lxml\_elementpath.py", line 229, in lxml._elementpath.prepare_predicate
SyntaxError: invalid predicate
```

One last thing: I do not wish to use `compound class names` cause few websites produce them dynamically. Thanks.

Comment: `.find()` only supports basic xpath. Try `.xpath()` instead. Like `regular = item.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"Regular")]')[0].text` (untested). http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Haley for your quick reply. It seems `.xpath()` and `.cssselect()` used within `.fromstring()` and `.HTML()` work identically. You should make it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` only supports basic xpath.

Try `.xpath()` instead.

Example (untested)...

```
regular = item.xpath('.//span[contains(@class,"Regular")]')[0].text
```

See http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html for more details.